# stop/restart X server

Tags: x11, configuration, lubuntu

I want to generate xorg.conf but for that X needs to not be running. How do I stop X or start without it?
I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> but the X server is still running.

I'm running Lubuntu 14.10.

Comment: You can make changes to xorg.conf while X is running. You just need to restart X in order for the changes to take effect: `killall X` will restart it for you.

Comment: @drs `X: no process found` is what I got. I made minimal ubuntu installation. I've installed `X11` and then `openbox` and `fbpanel`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Then I had to run <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and log in the second terminal, otherwise it would just sit there with dark screen. To start it back up:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lxdm stop
```

`lxdm` starts/stops the X server.

Comment: The default installation of lubuntu since 12.04 uses lightdm rather than lxdm as its display manager, I think - in which case it would more likely be `sudo service lightdm stop`